# Meaning of the inverse of a differential operator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory, fourier-transform, greens-function, integral-operators

Consider the Poisson's equation $$\nabla^2\phi(\textbf{x})=-\rho(\textbf{x})/\epsilon_0.$$ What is the meaning of the inverse operator in the following $$\phi(\textbf{x})=-\frac{1}{\nabla^2}\frac{\rho(\textbf{x})}{\epsilon_0}.$$

How do I show that $\frac{1}{\nabla^2}$ is equivalent to an integral operator acting on $\rho(\textbf{x})$?

Comment: Depends on a bunch of things, like boundary conditions. Ideally you would use the Green's function; generically speaking, if $G$ is the Green's function of the linear operator $L$ then $G * f$ satisfies $L(G*f)=f$. In such cases, the operator $f \mapsto G*f$ is your "inverse" operator, and it is given by convolution with some (usually singular) kernel.

Comment: @Ian My question is, how can we show that in general $1/\nabla^2$ corresponds to an integral operator. How can we give a mathematical meaning to the object $1/\nabla^2$?

Comment: You need to say something about boundary conditions for this to make any sense, because $\nabla^2$ itself is not invertible at all. If you intend to talk about the Poisson equation on the whole space, then this result (and an explicit calculation of the Green's function in arbitrary dimensions) is easily found in a PDE reference like Evans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using physical notation, it is reasonable to assume that your boundary condition is $\phi(\vec x) \to 0 $ as $|\vec x| \to \infty$. In this situation, the solution is
$$ \phi(\vec x) = \frac 1 {4\pi \epsilon_0}\iiint d^3 \vec y \frac{\rho(\vec y)}{ |\vec x - \vec y|}.$$
So
$$ - \frac 1 {\nabla^2} \frac{\rho(\vec x)}{\epsilon_0} = \frac 1 {4\pi \epsilon_0}\iiint d^3 \vec y \frac{\rho(\vec y)}{ |\vec x - \vec y|}.$$

As Ian mentioned in his comment, there is a rigorous proof of this in Evans, but, assuming you're a physicist, I would prefer to explain it like this:

The function
$$ G(\vec x, \vec y) = \frac 1 {4\pi \epsilon_0 |\vec x - \vec y|}$$
is the electric potential around a point charge at position $\vec y$. In other words, it is the solution to
$$ \nabla^2_{\vec x} G(\vec x, \vec y) = - \frac 1 {\epsilon_0} \delta^3(\vec x - \vec y), $$
obeying vanishing boundary conditions at infinity. [This is essentially Gauss' law from vector calculus. You can derive it by considering volume integrals of both sides of the PDE on spherical balls around $\vec y$.]

The solution I gave you can be thought of as a sum over the electric potential contributions from the infinitesimal charges  $\rho(\vec y) d^3 \vec y$ at all possible positions $\vec y$.